# Show that a stationary point is always a local maximum (picture)

Tags: calculus

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEl3L.png

I understand that a SP is a max/min when the derivative around is rising and falling etc., but I don't understand the book's solution to c. Where are they getting it from? Is x < a an interval or an inequality?

Comment: Try sketching what you think the function looks like. It'll help, I promise.

Comment: I know it would definitely help if I sketched it, but that still doesn't tell me how they got their solution. Does the "If" imply that they had used the sketch?

Comment: The solution basically says $f'(a^-)>0$ and $f'(a^+)>0$.  Since the function goes from increasing to decreasing about $a$, $f(a)$ is a maximum.

Answer (score 0):

The function is an $S$ shaped function which increases from $-\infty $ to $x=a$ where it kisses the $x-axis$ and turns around and decreases for while so $x=a$ is a local maximizer.